# Need to install 'webpack-dev-server'

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I have cloned a repo from GitHub for a project. I've already installed node (-v 14.17.5) and npm (-v7.20.6), however when I run `npm start` I get the following code. I've tried reinstalling node and npm several times but I keep getting the same error:

```
$ npm start

> simplefolio@1.0.1 start
> webpack server --config webpack.dev.js --open

[webpack-cli] You need to install 'webpack-dev-server' for running 'webpack serve'.
Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-dev-server/bin/cli-flags'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\edwin\Desktop\git\simplefolio\node_modules\@webpack-cli\serve\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\edwin\Desktop\git\simplefolio\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js
- C:\Users\edwin\Desktop\git\simplefolio\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\bootstrap.js
- C:\Users\edwin\Desktop\git\simplefolio\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js
- C:\Users\edwin\Desktop\git\simplefolio\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js
```

Comment: did you install? https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-dev-server

Comment: Yes. I get the same error

Comment: @EdwinCastro Can you share `package.json` file? Also, if it is public repo, can you share repo link as well?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`, then `npm i` again

Answer (score 0):

Remove node modules, then `npm i` again

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have node 16.13.0 and npm 7.20.1. Removing nodes_modules, package-lock.json and run npm cache clean --force alone didn't help. The key change for me is upgrading npm version to the latest (8.7.0), then combining with clean install.